# Socketio not correctly working with Nodejs/Typescript and React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, sockets

I have been trying to make `socket.io` work with my `Nodejs and Typescript` backend and `React + JSX` frontend, this is my first experience with `socket.io` but it has been a nightmare.
This is the server.ts file

```js
import Express, {Application} from 'express';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

const app: Application = Express();
import http from 'http';
//getting the Socket Type from socket io
import {Socket} from 'socket.io';
//importing the IO object form seperate file
import {init, socket} from './utils/socketio'; // <--- seperate socketio.ts file

import teacher_route from './Routes/teacher';
import student_route from './Routes/student';
import cookie_check_route from './Routes/cookieCheck';
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import cors from 'cors';
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

const server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
dotenv.config();
app.use(cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true,
}));

//initializing the io
init(server);


app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/t', teacher_route);
app.use('/s', student_route);
app.use('/c', cookie_check_route);

//connecting the io
socket().on("connection", (socket: Socket)=> {
    console.log("reached server")
    socket.on("joined", (data: object)=> {
        console.log("reached joined")
        //@ts-ignore
        socket.emit("joined2", {
            //@ts-ignore
            full_name: "student[0].full_name",
            attendance: "",
            average_score: "",
            average_attendance: ""
        })
    })
})


server.listen(process.env.PORT);
```

SocketIO.ts file on the backend

```js
import socketIo, {Socket} from 'socket.io';
let io: any;


//@ts-ignore
const init = (httpServer)=>{
    //@ts-ignore
    io = socketIo(httpServer, {
        cors: true,
        origins: ["http://127.0.0.1:3000"]
    });
    return io;
}

const getIO = () => {
    if(!io){
        throw new Error("Socket.io is not initialised!");
    }
    return io;
}

const socket = () => {
    return getIO().on("connection", (socket: Socket)=> {
        // console.log("inside socketio.ts file")
        return socket;
    })
}

export {init, getIO, socket};
```

This is the `useEffect` hook in StudentPortal.jsx file

```js
useEffect(()=> {
        setLoader(true)
        socket.emit("joined"); // <--- emmiting an event
        axios.get(`${config.apiEndpoint}/s/checkclasses`, {
            withCredentials: true
        }).then(response => {
            setClasses(true);
            setDisableSubmit(false);
            setLoader(false)
            if(response.data.class_data_array){
                setClassData(response.data.class_data_array.reverse());
            }
        });
    }, [addedClass])
```

And Finally this is the Class.jsx file where i want to finally get that event

```js
    socket.on("joined2", (data)=> {
        // setClassData([...classData, data]);
        console.log("Class.jsx socket");
    })
```

So the gist of this is that i am emmitting an event from `StudentPortal.jsx` named `joined` and listening for it in the `Server.ts` and in it's body, i am emmitting another event named `Joined2` and listening for it in the `Class.jsx`, i have tried many many different things, placed socket connection in different files, tried to connect first and then emmit, and so much more, nothing seems to work.
Any help is truly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: What doesnt work? Is the connection established? Where does it fail. Please provide more information to get help. "It does not work" will not cut it. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask